# how to reconcile maven development directory structure to maven release directory structure

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I use standard maven directory structure for my project http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

However, this is problematic because configuration files are going to be in jar file. There is some discussion on reading the config files from predefined location as [How to get the path of a running JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file/320554#320554)

But I am trying to package my jar file without any configuration files in it and make the directory structure look similar to any other open source projects that we download

```
project|
        --lib
       |
        --conf
       |
        --docs
       |
        --src
```

I prefer not to do any source code changes (ex:all my config files are in source path for maven development and I just read the files directly without prepending with the path); if I have to change path to config files in source code, what should I do to make the path work both in development and in production
My questions

1)how can I have current "development" directory structure as is, but have my "production" release directory will look similar to that of any apache(say) project

2)for every release, what changes should I do in pom.xml so that the version numbers are appended to jar and incremented

I prefer not to do any source/java code changes (ex:all my config files are in source path for maven development and I just read the files directly without prepending with the path); if I have to change path to config files in source code, what should I do to make the path work both in development and in production

(I am using Maven and Eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to share some more tips based on what I digged out (@superbob gave good explanation).
This is easier said than done....

I wanted to create jar (executable first) and copy this jar file into zip (along with few other directories for releasing in to production)...it is easy if u can look at existing pom file than fiddling with existing pom.

Look here for an existing project(pom.xml) http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/tips-and-tricks/creating-a-runnable-binary-distribution-with-maven-assembly-plugin/

In my case, I had multiple pom files and it adds another layer of complexity for newbie like me..look here for multi module example with maven assembly plugin http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/multimodule/index.html

Last but not least, run the following command to make sure assembly is created

```
   mvn  clean install package assembly:single
```

Answer (score 1):

In my projects I use the [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to package the application in a *redistribuable* way :

Everything under `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources` is packaged inside the main jar (standard behaviour).

Then using assembly plugin, I create a zip containing 3 folders :

- `/lib` : contains the main jar + all the dependencies
- `/bin` : contains the additional files from the `src/main/scripts` maven source folder (startup shell scripts)
- `/etc` (or `/conf`) : contains the additional files from the `src/main/config` maven source folder (config files)

I find this setup very convenient as it is really close to the initial [maven standard layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) (`src/main/java` + `src/main/resources` in the main jar and other folders taken appart), still being adapted to my projects.

Comment: How do you add version number to the release? Not sure how maven release if maven release can be used for directory structure http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-releasing.html  (I am newbie )

Comment: @kashili kashili, release numbers should be appended automatically to the artifact filename using assembly plugin. The version number is the one in your pom

Answer (score 0):

You can use your existing resources by mentioning those resource directories in [Maven Resource Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html).

add following code to build (  tag )section of your pom.xml

```
<resources>
 <resource>
   <directory>[your folder here]</directory>
 </resource>
</resources>
```

you can add several non maven standard resources over here ( anything other that src/main/resources ).